# how to sum rows in my dataframe Pandas with specific condition?

Tags: pandas, sum

Could anyone help me ?

I want to sum the values with the format:

```
print (...+....+)
```

for example:

```
a             b
France        2
Italie        15
Croatie       7
```

I want to make the sum of France and Croatie.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: `df.loc[df['a'].isin(['France','Croatie']),'b'].sum()`?

Comment: Thank you, yes it works ! But I also have to make substraction that's why I ask is it's possible to write it with the format: print (...+....+...-....-...)

Comment: Add column 'sign' and put 1 for + or - 1 for minus. Then multiply column 'b' by the sign and add New column for data - c for example. Then do the sum

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions:

- set column *a* as the index,
- using *loc* select rows for the "wanted" values,
- take column *b*,
- sum the values found.

So the code can be:

```
result = df.set_index('a').loc[['France', 'Croatie']].b.sum()
```

Note double square brackets. The outer pair is the "container" of index values
passed to *loc*.
The inner part, and what is inside, is a list of values.

To **subtract** two sums (one for some set of countries and the second for another set),
you can run e.g.:

```
wrk = df.set_index('a').b
result = wrk.loc[['Italie', 'USA']].sum() - wrk.loc[['France', 'Croatie']].sum()
```

Comment: Thank you ! I will try with your code ! Someone showed me a simple way to make addition and subtraction with : print (..+...-) (only 11 rows to add or substract) but I forgot how he did that... Thank you so much !